# User and admin MiKTeX Update

Tags: updating, miktex-update

I like to be updated. So from time to time I do an update of MiKTeX. I did it some days ago and just to see I do it again today.

If I do the update with MiKTeK Update (admin) I got nothing to update (which sound quite logical since I've done the update some days ago)

[image]

[image]

But if I do the update with MiKTeK update (NON admin) I got four packages obsolete (to be removed)

[image]

The four files are in two folders. The one of the *user* install

> C:\Users\Dominique\AppData\Roaming\MiKTeX\2.9\miktex\bin\x64\MiKTeX209-harfbuzz.dll

and the one of the *admin* install

> C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\miktex\bin\x64\MiKTeX209-harfbuzz.dll

Why the user update tell me to remove these files and that  there are obsolete ?? (that is not the case !). Should I do it ?

I guess it would do no any harm since the same files are also in the *admin* install, but I don't get the logic of the message.

PS: I Checked that the both files are exactely the same version in both folders

**EDIT**

And by the way when you use the MiKTeK Settings (**admin**) to launch the **Update wizard** (so in fact the **MiKteK Update**), it is the **user** version of the MiKteK Update wich is used (not the **admin** one). That can be confusing.

[image]

[image]

Comment: If miktex tells me that something should be removed I let it do it if I don't know about a concrete reason (e.g. a bug report) not to do it. If like in your case this removes double versions of .dll in the user tree I would certainly advise do it. Regarding the menu entry in the package manager: make a bug report (I never use this menu entry as last time I tried it was broken anyway).

Comment: How do I make a bug report ? On Sourceforge ?

Comment: The new issue tracker is here: https://github.com/MiKTeX/miktex

Comment: It's done  [Bug report](https://github.com/MiKTeX/miktex/issues/31)

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the given bug report results in a corrected version ...